# Best practices for adding/editing UI table data while filtering

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, filtering

Does any one know If there are any best-practices for editing/adding data in UI table while its data is filtered?

**Example 1:**

Suppose we have a table with two options: add new record and edit selected one. Moreover, the table has an option to filter data over column A.

Now, if the table is filtered by filtering column A with value '1' and I want to add a new record with value in column A that matches filter requirements, what should happen:

1. The table should refresh and display filtered records with selected newly added record.
2. The table should reset filter and show all records witch new one selected.
3. The table should do nothing and display filtered records as they were. Newly added record will be displayed when the filter resets.

For me intuitively the best solution is number 1. But then how to solve the problem in example number 2:

**Example 2:**

If the table is filtered by filtering column A with value '1' and I want to add a new record that in column A has value '2' what should happen:

1. The table should display filtered records with selected newly added record despite it does not matche the filter.
2. The table should reset the filter, and all records should be displayed with new one selected.
3. The table should do nothing and display filtered records as they were.

---

The same story is when we have filtered records, and in selected record we want to edit value upon which the filtering took place. Does the edited record should than disapear or filtre should be reset?

Or maybe the best way is to disable add/edit operations while filter is on?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is any best practices about it but I have also encountered the problem before. Two different solutions as I came up with:

1. Edited/Inserted record should not be filtered until the next time a filter is applied or filter is reset. The record should also be shown different (i.e. darker background color, or an icon, or tooltip) than others implying it was edited and is not being filtered.
2. The record should be left in focus after being edited or inserted. As soon as it loses focus, filter should be applied to it. The ideal solution is if the record is filtered out, it shouldn't immediately go out of vision.  For instance it may go invisible with an animation.

Comment: I like solution 2, very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked the google docs and libre office, both of them just display the new record regardless of the filter. You need to re-apply the filter to hide them from view (in both cases the column "A" is filtered by "value 1"):

[image: google docs spreadsheet]

[image: libre office spreadsheet]